# iPhone 4S won't connect to Pebble after forgetting phone

Tags: ios, bluetooth

My iPhone 4S running iOS 9.3.5 won't connect back to Pebble smartwatch after forgetting the phone from the Pebble's settings section and it won't connect back over the Pebble app.

How can I connect them back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to forget both Pebble XXXX and Pebble XXXX-LE from the Settings on the iPhone. Then, you will be able to reconnect them through the Pebble app on the phone.